# How to create a stream in PHP just like fopen() function does, but without enabling allow_url_include and allow_url_fopen?

Tags: php, file, stream

I need to create a stream without using `fopen()` function in php if `allow_url_include` OR `allow_url_fopen` is disabled.

And if disabled how can I turned them on without using `ini_set()` function

Comment: Are they disabled because your web host doesn't allow them?

Comment: Yes. they are disabled. But I wanna try the function fopen.
although str_getcsv() doesn't work well. it breaks where there is a line break, comma, special char etc.